# Unable to generate APKs using bundletool in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

As mentioned in [Bundletool Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool)

I'm giving following command on Android Studio terminal:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

I'm getting following error:

```
'bundletool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've downloaded the [bundletool 0.6.0 jar](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases/tag/0.6.0)

On [bundletool github](https://github.com/google/bundletool), there are no steps given to install it on windows.

Comment: hi..did you get the solution for this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Execute bundletool from the command line as follows. Make sure paths to java/bundletool/aab/jks are set and correct.

```
java -jar bundletool-all-0.6.0.jar build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks --ks=keystore.jks --ks-key-alias=key0
```

Comment: Can all androids read apks? I'm trying to open a generated apks file. My android device (which is an old one) says it cannot open it. Is this due to malfunction in the application or because the phone really just can't read apks?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking to generate a universal APK from the .aab file on mac, you can use the below steps

- Use the following command to generate the '.apks' file from the '.aab' file:
  ***java -jar bundletool-all-1.1.0.jar build-apks --bundle=/path_to_aab/myapp.aab --output=/path_to_aab/myapp.apks --mode=universal***
- Rename the myapp.apks file to myapp.zip
- Unzip and you will find universal apk

Comment: this is correct, but the universal app doesn't load.